# C++ If a function calls another function which accepts a parameter and prints the result. Why won't it print?

Tags: c++

The main method calls the `twice()` method. The `twice()` method calls the `triple()` and `quadruple()` method. For some reason they aren't printing. Please let me know what I need to fix?

```
using namespace std;

class firstClass{
public:
        double twice(int g){
            double result = g*2;
            triple(g);
            quadruple(g);
            return result;
        }
        double triple(int g){
            double result = g*3;
            cout<< result;
        }
         double quadruple(int g){
            double result = g*4;
            cout<< result;
        }
};


int main(){
    cout<<"Please enter a number you'd like to multiply";
    double a;
    cin>>a;
    double g;
    double twice(a);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed to `return result;` after printing.

Comment: `double twice(a);` is basically `double twice = a;`.

Comment: Your main function doesn't call anything. Your `main` declares a `double` variable named "twice", and sets it to `a`. This has nothing to do with some method of some unrelated class that happens to have the same name.

Comment: you need to create an object of your class

Comment: You're trying to call a function of a class object without creating a class object.

Comment: This question should not be closed as a typo. It contains multiple errors and is the result of legitimate misunderstanding.

Comment: I think you need to read the introduction to classes and objects in your favourite C++ book. (And the first chapter on functions, too.)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you have the following:

```
double g;
double twice(a);
```

This line doesn't actually call your function.  You've effectively declared a variable (of type `double`, called `twice`), and constructed it with the value stored in `a`.

Additionally, the actual function `twice()` is a *member function* of your class `firstClass`, so you'll need to create an instance of that in order to call the member.

```
firstClass obj;
double g = obj.twice(a);
```

Comment: You're right!  Edited.  There's a lot wrong to unpack here.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Is it UB even if those functions aren't called?

Comment: @jfh I don't think so, but they would be called with the fix to calling `twice`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Have had to work in a code base which returned an integer, whose body only initialized an integer to 0, omitted the return, but its result was never used. I suspect it just popped whatever was on the stack (and in debug builds that's exactly what it did), but the code originated from the late 90s (in a completely static environment) and "just worked". Would be interesting to see what a modern compiler does with it.

Comment: @jfh In C++ it's explicitly Undefined Behavior. I think in C you can fail to return as long as you don't use the return value but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There was a few issues. Triple and quadruple both had missing return statements. You also needed to create a `firstClass` object to use the member functions on.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class firstClass{
  public:
    double twice(int g){
        double result = g*2;
        return result;
    }
    double triple(int g){
        double result = g*3;
        return result; // had missing return here
    }
      double quadruple(int g){
        double result = g*4;
        return result; // had missing return here
    }
};

int main(){
  double response;
  
  firstClass my_obj; // you need a firstClass object to use those functions on.

  cout << "Please enter a number you'd like to multiply: ";
  cin >> response;

  cout << "\nWwice = " << my_obj.twice(response);

  cout << "\nTriple = " << my_obj.triple(response);

  cout << "\nQuadruple = " << my_obj.quadruple(response);

  return 0;
}
```